# Spring boot OAuth 2 security get access token from Refresh token(if expired)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have implemented Spring boot Oauth 2 security it works fine but when I try to get access token (if expired) from refresh token it gives me an error

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "admin"
}
```

Console Log

```
Handling error: UsernameNotFoundException, admin
```

Following is my code

1.WebSecurityConfigure

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class EmployeeSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().antMatchers("/user/getEmployeesList")
            .hasAnyRole("USER").anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
            .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationMgr) throws Exception {
        authenticationMgr.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin")
            .authorities("ROLE_USER");
    ;
    }
}
```

2.AuthorizationServerConfigure

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;


     @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
            security
                    .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                    .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                    .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
        }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("MagicUser").authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token","password")
                .authorities("CLIENT").scopes("openid", "read", "write", "trust").resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .redirectUris("http://10.9.6.31:8090/showEmployees").accessTokenValiditySeconds(5000).secret("secret")
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(50000);

    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST);
        ;
    }
}
```

Please help me to figure out this issue

Access token request (if expired)

```
    http://10.9.6.31:8091/oauth/token
    Body parameter
   grant_type=refresh_token
  refresh_token=78d2ab82-46a2-4b70-a9e8-e3f9e5ddfec6
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have to send an authorization header in the request to authenticate the client.
Check [OAuth client authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3) and [Refreshing an access token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-6) specifications in OAuth 2.0 specification.